# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded with nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

We using a mongodb call to retrieve documents inside socket event which is been called during every page loading/socket creation so that we are getting `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Kindly check the below code.

```js
socket.on('addUser', function (userid){
  connectedSocket[userid] = socket;
  socket.UserId = userid;
  
  //getLostMessages(userid);
  console.log('new user added : '+userid);
  lostMesgsdb.findByReceiver(userid, function(err, mesgRecords){
   if(mesgRecords)
   {
    if(mesgRecords.length == 0)
    {
     console.log('no lost messages found');
    }
    else
    {
     // console.log(mesgRecords); //connectedSocket[userid]
     connectedSocket[userid].emit('lostMessages', mesgRecords);
     
     lostMesgsdb.delete(userid, function( error, docs) {
      console.log('messages are deleted for user : '+userid);
     });
    }
   }
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.  This occurs when stack is full.  I don't see any kind of loops in the code.  Check your code for infinite loops.. Learn about set immediate and process nexttick in nodejs